# How to fix codeigniter url encode

Tags: codeigniter

I am having issue on pagination url

This is my first `url` am passing parameter

```
user?name=sdsad&email=&role=&status=
```

am getting 20 datas

```
?name%3Ddinesh%26email%3D%26role%3D%26status%3Dstart=1
```

this is my pagination configuration

```
$config['query_string_segment'] = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'start';
```

pagaination url is `/user?name%3Ddinesh%26email%3D%26role%3D%26status%3Dstart=1`

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty simple, just use PHP urlencode() before send in request which will be work.
Suppose you have multiple variable as

```
$name=" Denesh Kumar";
//$name=urlencode(" Denesh Kumar");
$name=urlencode($name);
$address= "12, 5A, Mumbai";
//$address=urlencode(" 12, 5A, Mumbai");
$address=urlencode($address);
// Then pass in the controller as 
 '.../name'.'='.$name.'&address='.'$address
```

Hope it will work.
Thank you!